# Static variable scope in Servie Fabric Application

Tags: c#, static, azure-service-fabric

I am running my Service Fabric Stateful service in local
with 3 partitions and 3 Replica.

The application has a public static variable and the value is initialized in the 'startup' class.

I was assuming that the scope of the static variable was per replica. 
But It seems the static variable scope is shared between all instance in a node.

ie. I am accessing the static variable from Partition 1 Primary Replica but its giving value from Partition 3 Secondary Replica where both replica reside in **same node**. 
The value of static variable seems to be overwritten in some order inside the same node.

What is the scope of Static variable inside Stateful service fabric application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each replica of a stateful service or instance of a stateless service *of the same service type* is an *instantiation* of your StatefulService- or StatelessService-derived service class (the one with RunAsync) in the same process and in the same AppDomain. In other words, all the replicas of a service that are placed on the same node are just a bunch of .NET objects in the same process. So yes, a static variable will be seen across them. Static variables are not recommended. If you need "just one" of something, use a singleton pattern and scope singleton instances to service replicas/instances, which you'll have to do yourself with a look-up table.

Comment: Thanks for this commenting.  Can you please elaborate a little more why static variable is not recommended?  Is there a possibility of some critical issue?

Comment: @swcraft, I know this answer is very late, but for others finding this, the reason to not use static variables is partially due to this oddity (generally one wouldn't expect that the node would matter, that each partition would be isolated from each other one), but for a stateful service the problem is worse.  If Service Fabric decides to move your partition from one node to another, any data not stored in either an IReliableStateManager or an IActorStateManager would be lost, so data in a static variable would be lost, and your logic probably doesn't expect that.